# Chrome running slow in fullscreen mode (not Flash related)

Tags: 14.04, graphics, intel-graphics, integrated

Got a new Intel NUC running Ubuntu 14.04. Chrome shows dramatically degraded performance when I fullscreen any tab by pressing F11. It happens on YouTube and Netflix, but it's also true even on simple webpages like Wikipedia. I can tell just by scrolling up and down. The apparent framerate drops from at least 20fps to about 2fps. Netflix plays videos fine even when the window is maximized, and fullscreen is only slightly larger than that.

Firefox also does not show this problem.

I assume what's happening is that Chrome is changing the display settings to something not well supported by my graphics hardware. Here's the output from `sudo lshw -class display`. Any known fixes? Thanks.

```
*-display               
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     version: 09
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
     resources: irq:47 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, go to the url **chrome://gpu**.

It should look something like this:
[image: click here to show image if not displayed]

If so, go to the url **chrome://flags**.

1. Go to **Override software rendering list** and click **enable**.
2. Go to **Enable experimental canvas features** and click **enable**.

Then, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and search for the word **raster**.

1. Change **Enable display list 2D canvas** to **Enabled**.
2. Change **Enable GPU rasterization** to **Force Enabled for all
   layers**.
3. Change **Enable zero-copy rasterizer** to **Enabled**.

When you are done, click **Reload** and go to the URL chrome://gpu and it should look like this:

[image: click here to see image if not displayed]

Hopefully, this should make a difference.

Partially adapted from [this article on Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/enable-hardware-acceleration-in-chrome.html).

Comment: Just as a followup to anyone else who tries this out: it did fix the problem but it caused really weird artifacts rendering images on some web pages. Images would be missing, replaced by other images on the page, flipped, or partially grayed out. I've changed everything back to default settings and fullscreen seems okay so far, so hopefully whatever problem I had was fixed in a Chrome update. Thanks again!

Comment: @Cosmologicon Make sure your GPU is properly detected by the system by going to system Settings > Details. Sometimes Gallium will show up when it's not supposed to and this will cause the system to lag and things won't work properly sometimes.