# Chrome webgl issue

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, google, webgl, google-maps

Guys I know it seems a duplicated issue but I read the previous answers and none of them worked for me so I opened this issue here.

- I use ubuntu 16.04
- nvdia drivers 361 (recommended)
- and google chrome 51.0.2704.79 (64-bit)

When I try to open google maps I face with a webgl crash what should I do

Starting Chrome from terminal and reproducing the crash ends in a long output like that.

```
[12346:12346:0603/183820:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(14683)] [.CommandBufferContext.DisplayCompositor-0x25a662af5dc0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[12346:12346:0603/183820:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(7857)] [.CommandBufferContext.DisplayCompositor-0x25a662af5dc0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
[12346:12346:0603/183820:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(14683)] [.CommandBufferContext.DisplayCompositor-0x25a662af5dc0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[12346:12346:0603/183820:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(7857)] [.CommandBufferContext.DisplayCompositor-0x25a662af5dc0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
[12346:12346:0603/183820:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(14683)] [.CommandBufferContext.DisplayCompositor-0x25a662af5dc0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[12346:12346:0603/183820:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(7857)] [.CommandBufferContext.DisplayCompositor-0x25a662af5dc0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
[12346:12346:0603/183820:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(14683)] [.CommandBufferContext.DisplayCompositor-0x25a662af5dc0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
[12346:12346:0603/183820:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(7857)] [.CommandBufferContext.DisplayCompositor-0x25a662af5dc0]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.
[12346:12346:0603/183820:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(14683)] [.CommandBufferContext.DisplayCompositor-0x25a662af5dc0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glCreateAndConsumeTextureCHROMIUM: invalid mailbox name
```

Complete [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16949686/).

Comment: Start chrome from terminal and add the crash output to your original post above.

Comment: You are refering to other posts and things you already tried but give no details about those posts. Please add them if possible.

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/702879/chrome-running-slow-in-fullscreen-mode-not-flash-related

Comment: Please post the info from the crash.

Comment: @dufte I did http://paste.ubuntu.com/16949686/ here is the result. It keeps going like this

Comment: ok It happens when I try to use google maps I provide a terminal session for chrome above and you can find my system details on the firs message

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it this way. I opened `chrome://flags` and enabled `webgl-draft-extensions`.

After restarting Chrome the maps work without any issues.